# Should I be creating a class instead of a struct so that I can put the data into an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, struct, nsarray

Is it possible to create something like a C `struct` for Objective-C? I need to be able to use it in an `NSArray` so it cannot be a traditional `struct`. Right now I am declaring a whole class just to accomplish this and I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

What I currently have:

```
@interface TextureFile : NSObject
@property NSString *name;
@property GLKTextureInfo *info;
@end

@implementation TextureFile
@synthesize name = _name;
@synthesize info = _info;
@end

NSMutableArray *textures;
```

What I want to do:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *name;
    GLKTextureInfo *info;
} TextureFile;

NSMutable array *textures;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what kind of data you're using, the example you are using in your question seems okay for a struct.

If you need to store a C struct in an `NSArray`, which requires an object, you can convert the C-struct to `NSValue` and store it like that, you then convert back to its C struct type when you read it.

Check the Apple [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Given this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *name;
    GLKTextureInfo *info;
} TextureFile;
```

To store it:

```
TextureFile myStruct;
// set your stuct values

NSValue *anObj = [NSValue value:&myStruct withObjCType:@encode(TextureFile)];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anObj, nil];
```

To read it again:

```
NSValue *anObj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
TextureFile myStruct;
[anObj getValue:&myStruct];
```

Comment: I guess this would work but it seems even more inconvenient than the first method :P

Comment: Well, otherwise you can just create your subclass of NSObject, personally I believe that that is more inconvenient :) it depends what kind of data your sending around. Your example seems fit for a struct